# Unable to update Console Cursor Info (PCONSOLE_CURSOR_INFO) due to security

Tags: windows, visual-studio, security, console, acl

In console application, I want to write the output at a specific location and there should be no cursor at the console (Windows CMD). To do so, I got following way:

```
HANDLE hdl = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE); 
if (hdl == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
{
    printf("Error : Unable to get console handle.\n");
    return 0;
}
PCONSOLE_CURSOR_INFO lpConsoleCursorInfo = { NULL };
if (!GetConsoleCursorInfo(hdl, &lpConsoleCursorInfo))
{
    printf("Error : Unable to get console cursor information.\n");
    return 0;
}
lpConsoleCursorInfo->dwSize = 1; //App exit at this point with error code 0xC0000005h
```

I got runtime error 0xC0000005h. By searching, I have reach at the conclusion that it is a security level issue, and to setup access level SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR is used.

I am unable to find the way how to set the access level to STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE that already created and associated with my console application by visual studio console application.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: This code does not compile?

Comment: @Anders this code compile and execute but exit at nominated line under Visual Studio 2022.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no security issue, you simply don't understand how Windows pointer types work. `PCONSOLE_CURSOR_INFO` is just a pointer, remove the P.

```
CONSOLE_CURSOR_INFO ConsoleCursorInfo = { NULL };
if (!GetConsoleCursorInfo(hdl, &ConsoleCursorInfo)) ...
else ConsoleCursorInfo.dwSize = ...
```

Comment: Wow! your code worked and executed well as per requirement. Sorry I am not good in native c (point based language) but I am working in reference based language java and c#. But your code help me a lot.